# Flex IBM ILOG (Elixir 3.0) Interactive map

Tags: apache-flex, ilog, ilog-elixir

I develop interactive map: user can zoom some area and place labels by mouse click.
I am creating customSkin:

```
<ibm:Scroller top="0" left="0" width="100%" height="100%" id="scroller" doubleClickEnabled="true"
skinClass="com.ibm.ilog.elixir.skins.spark.ScrollerSkin">
<ibm:MapGroup id="mapGroup">
<ibm:MapFeatureGroup id="featureGroup" featureRenderer="skins.DistrictRenderer" keyField="district"/>
<ibm:MapDataGroup id="objectsDataGroup"
zoomable="false"
itemRenderer="skins.DistrictObjectsRenderer"
keyField="district" />
</ibm:MapGroup>
</ibm:Scroller>
```

In DistrictRenderer I dispatching mouse click.
But how can I place labels?
May be I must pass x,y to DistrictObjectsRenderer and there create new labels?

Comment: could you publish your project somewhere with working runnable sample and SrvView, and I will show you the place to put your label placement function. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Its a final solution:

RegionMapSkin.mxml:

```
<ibm:Scroller top="0" left="0" width="100%" height="100%" id="scroller" skinClass="com.ibm.ilog.elixir.skins.spark.ScrollerSkin">
    <ibm:MapGroup id="mapGroup">
        <ibm:MapFeatureGroup id="featureGroup" 
                             featureRenderer="com.skins.DistrictRenderer" />
    <ibm:MapDataGroup id="objectsGroup" 
                          zoomable="false" 
                          itemRenderer="com.skins.ObjectsRenderer" 
                          dataProvider="{ObjectsModel.getInstance().items}" />
    </ibm:MapGroup>
</ibm:Scroller>
```

ObjectsRenderer.mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:DataRenderer xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"                               
            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
            xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
            xmlns:ibm="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/ilog/elixir/2010"

            left="{data.lon}"
            top="{data.lat}">
    <s:Label text="{data.title}" 
         color="#ffffff" 
         backgroundColor="#AB191A"
         paddingLeft="3" paddingRight="3" paddingTop="4" paddingBottom="1"
         top="-18" left="3"/>

    <s:Ellipse width="6" height="6">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="#AB191A" />
        </s:fill>
    </s:Ellipse>
</s:DataRenderer>
```

And onMouseClick handler in DistrictRenderer:

```
private function onMouseClick(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    var mapFeature:MapFeature = MapFeatureRenderer(e.currentTarget).mapFeature;
    var map:RegionMap = app.map;
    var p:Point = new Point(e.localX, e.localY);
    p = map.mapToLongLat(p);
    ObjectsModel.getInstance().items.addItem({
        'title': parameters.title,
        'lon': parameters.lon,
        'lat': parameters.lat
    });
}
```